# Why can't I detach a disk from a VM? It says it's because it can't find the storage. But I already deleted the storage

Tags: azure, storage, disk, detach

Why can't I detach a disk from a VM? It says it's because it can't find the storage. But I already deleted the storage.
Now what? How can I delete such disk?

Comment: No, if the disk is attached with VM, you could not delete the storage account. If possible, could you show detailed error log in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look with process explorer, and see if it gives which process has the VM open.
[from this link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)